# How to pass header to WebView in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, postdata

I am passing post data as Json using postUrl() to WebView in Android. Now I want to pass a header "Content-Type: application/json" also along with that. How to achieve it?

Comment: see my ans it will help u

Answer (score 0):

may this will help u :)

```
       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_src);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
httpclient.setParams(httpParameters);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(str,"UTF-8");
    se.setContentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(se); 

     httpPost.setHeader("userId", ""+userId);//userID
     httpPost.setHeader("machineId", machineId);//deviceUserMachineID

     response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what response will httpclient return? It can be set to WebView right?

Comment: data which web return to us that is response dude

Comment: it is post method for web calling @Vivek

Comment: My question was the response which it will return will be in html format right?

Comment: yup whatever your response will this response string will get it

Comment: WebVew's loadUrl() method support headers to be passed. Is there no way to pass headers with postUrl() method? Because with the above method, it will first make httpconnection and pass data to the server, the the response will be set to WebView through loadData() method.

Comment: this is all about for webview @Vivek :) ohk u found all gr8

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754526/android-webview-post-request-with-custom-headers)
Doesn't look like you can actually send headers with postUrl(), only with loadUrl() method.

Answer (score 0):

it possible to post data with header i have done it in my project 
  I am posting you my code ...

```
            HttpParams par = new BasicHttpParams();
            //par.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            int timeoutConnection = 30000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(par, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(par, timeoutSocket);

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(par);
         //   httpClient.setParams(par);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                 httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                 if(postMessage==null)
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("please send post data as well");
                byte[] data =postMessage.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                System.out.println("Base64: "+base64);

                // httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                  httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(base64));

            httpPost.setHeader("token", app.getToken());


           httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


             is = httpEntity.getContent();
               System.out.println("httpEntity.getContent():"+ is );
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              is, "iso-8859-1"));

             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             is.close();
             data = sb.toString();
              //remember httpconnection should be in background thread 
              // if you use asynchtask then upper code should be in doinbackground method 
              //and in onpostexecution do data load in webview

             webview.loadData(data, "text/html","UTF-8");
```